# Select one element from each set but the selected element should not be repeated

Tags: algorithm, math, set, logic

I have a few sets, say 5 of them

`{1,2,3}`

`{2,4}`

`{1,2}`

`{4,5}`

`{2,3,5}`

Here, I need to choose at least 3 elements from any three sets(One element per set). Given that if an element is already selected, then it cannot be selected again.

Also check if any solution exists or not.

Eg

set `{1,2,3`} -> choose `1`

set `{2,4}` -> choose `2`

set `{1,2}` -> cannot choose since both `1` and `2` are chosen.

set `{2,5}` -> can only choose 5

Is there a way to achieve this? Simple explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: make S = union of all sets, and select 3 distinct elements from S

Comment: @KermittheFrog. Doesn't work since you might accidentally select two or three from the same set

Comment: give each set an index from 0..4, and make an array A of sets, where A[1] = { 0, 2}, A[2] = { 0,1,2,4}... (A[2] contains all indices of sets containing 2, etc)., now you can repeat select an index i from A as long as A[i] is not empty. for each selection i, set A[i] = empty

Comment: @KermittheFrog could you elaborate with an answer? That would be much helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need 3 elements, then the algorithm is quite simple. Just repeat the following procedure:

1. Select the set with the lowest heuristic. The heuristic is the length of the set, divided by the total occurrences of that set. If the set has zero elements, remove the set, and go to step 4. If there are two or more, you can choose any one of them.
2. Pick an element from that set. This is the element you'll choose.
3. Remove this element from every set.
4. If you have picked 3 elements or there are no more sets remaining, exit. Otherwise go to step 1.

This algorithm gives at least 3 elements whenever it's possible, even in the presence of duplicates. Here's the proof.

1. If the heuristic for a set is `<= 1`, picking an element from that set is basically free. It doesn't hurt the ability to use other sets at all.
2. If we are in a situation with 2 or more sets with heuristic `>1`, and we have to pick at least two elements, this is easy. Just pick one from the first, and the second one will have an element left, because it's length is `>1` because it's heuristic is `>1`.
3. If we are in a situation with 3 or more sets with heuristic `>1`, we can pick from the first set. After this we are left with at least two sets, where at least one of them has more than one element. We can't be left with two size one sets, because that would imply that the 3 sets we started with contain a duplicate length 2 set, which has heuristic 1. Thus we can pick all 3 elements.

Here is python code for this algorithm. The generator returns as many elements as it can manage. If it's possible to return at least 3 elements, it will. However after that, it doesn't always return the optimal solution.

```python
def choose(sets):
    # Copy the input, to avoid modification of the input
    s = [{*e} for e in sets]
    while True:
        # If there are no more sets remaining
        if not s:return
        # Remove based on length and number of duplicates
        m = min(s,key=lambda x:(len(x)/s.count(x)))
        s.remove(m)
        # Ignore empty sets
        if m:
            # Remove a random element
            e = m.pop()
            # Yield it
            yield e
            # Remove the chosen element e from other sets
            for i in range(len(s)):s[i].discard(e)

print([*choose([{1,2,3}, {2,4}, {1,2}, {4,5}, {2,3,5}])])
print([*choose([{1}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {1,2,4}])])
print([*choose([{1,2}, {2}, {2,3,4}])])
print([*choose([{1,2}, {2}, {2,1}])])
print([*choose([{1,2}, {1,3}, {1,3}])])
print([*choose([{1}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}])])
print([*choose([{1,3}, {2,3,4}, {2,3,4}, {2,3,4}, {2,3,4}])])
print([*choose([{1,5}, {2,3}, {1,3}, {1,2,3}])])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVI9b8IwEN35FSd1iVFEBYEFialT16pLFWUw@EKsxnZkO5QI8dvTc8JXUEG1FN3Ffu/e852rxhdGJ20rMIdNYYzDyKF3bDkCWi/wZqoGfIEgdVX7GLwBvjNSgDJC5nLDvTQaTH7FdEQHK0gPYzxCbiyEEwhls@7wp5AlwqetsVfpld67GhaB06cNCVAMJLCouNRSby9omRPCg1ta9LXVN1U@UJkdwpo7FEDOStRbXwDXAnSt1miDV1FXZbCO7sJUZFhJHbn4G5tVydVacNgvI@JHe/bqJhtTa08pYxeOm9hOLVLs9h5bHZyjqnzT@b91ra43HvjlYMmiUYAlKtR@gMLgbVKZKmJ37C@JpQA5hDfdJv4tFMZEc3aoz1JUPrekbEL3h4bDCvOTYX5kcItdPxxjS5fKbCKk23ArImSjUWUl9Scdnx5RepjGszg5xnCYxfMQ6D@EebzoNxNKMpaxP5gnwJBMyQN4X3h2Lvs/3PQ5atrLh/DE5OWOffKoYnK19iR5xF7ctGN6L9e2vw)

Comment: Wouldn't work for {1,2},{1,3},{1,3} if we choose 1 from the first set.

Comment: Thanks @AnishSharma, now it should work for duplicate inputs also

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
given your sets
0: {1,2,3}
1: {2,4}
2: {1,2}
3: {4,5}
4: {2,3,5}
A array of sets
set A[1] = { 0, 2}       // all sets containing 1
    A[2] = { 0, 1, 2, 4} // all sets containing 2
    A[3] = { 0, 4 }      // all sets containing 3
    A[4] = { 1, 3 }      // all sets containing 4
    A[5] = { 3, 4 }      // all sets containing 5
set<int> result;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  find k such that A[k] not empty
  if no k exist then "no solution"
  result.add(k)
  A[k] = empty
}
return result
```

Comment: How would you find K in each iteration? would that be a randomly selected?

Comment: yes. that would do. if you care about time complexity, you need something other than Array, like a priority queue, with key = (setsize,index)

Comment: This may fail for some inputs like `{2,3},{2},{5}` if you first remove the `2` from the first set. You have to have to do the smallest sets first

Comment: Not true

0:{2,3}
1:{2}
2:{5}

A[0] = empty;
A[1] = empty;
A[2] = {0,1};
A[3] = {0};
A[4] = empty;
A[5] = {2};

select 2, as A[2] not empty; set A[2] = empty;

A[0] = empty
A[1] = empty
A[2] = empty
A[3] = {0}
A[4] = empty
A[5] = {2}

select 3, as A[3] not empty; set A[3] = empty;

A[0] = empty
A[1] = empty
A[2] = empty
A[3] = empty
A[4] = empty
A[5] = {2}

select 5, as A[5] not empty; set A[5] = empty;

A[0] = empty
A[1] = empty
A[2] = empty
A[3] = empty
A[4] = empty
A[5] = empty

and we're are done

Comment: If so, how does your code handle the input {1,2,3,4,5}? Doesn't this wrongfully give a solution, when there is none?

Comment: uhmmm....I have to admit, that there is a problem with that one!!

Answer (score 0):

I think my idea is a bit overkill but it would work on any kind of sets with any number of sets in any size.

the idea is to transform the sets to bipartite graph. on one side you have each set, and on the other side you have the number which they contains.
and if a set contains a number you have a edge between those vertices.

eventually you're trying to find the maximum matching in the graph (maximum cardinality matching).
gladly it can be done with Hopcroft-Karp algorithm in O(√VE) time or even less with Ford–Fulkerson algorithm.

here some links for more source on maximum matching and the algorithms->

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm